# SQL Server database doesnt get updated

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, sqlconnection

Successful connection is established in the program. There is no exception thrown in the program. But the database is not updated. Multiple parameters are added to the connection.

Is there something wrong with the cast?

```
 SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
 cnn.Open();

 DateTime Todays = DateTime.Today;
 int Num = 0;

 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE   tblMusic SET  Dt_last_played = convert(datetime,@1,5) ,  no_of_times = @3  WHERE Location = @5 ", cnn);

 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("1", Todays));            
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("3", Num));          
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("5", MediaElementObj.Source.ToString()));

 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Even though the process is not halted and error is not shown, the database is not updated.

Comment: There is no `MediaElement` in the code: do you mean `MediaElementObj`? If yes then what is its value when you get an `InvalidOperationException`? What is the error message in the `SqlException`?

Comment: There is a `MediaElement` in the function and `MediaElementObj` is its object. It seems that the project doesn't show any exceptions and hault the process but the database is not updated . and `ArgumentException, OperationExceptions` are seen in all the adding parameters when the mouse is hovered on top.

Comment: All of those exceptions come with a message and a stack trace. Can you tell us what the message is and which line that is shown as throwing the exception?

Comment: It doesn't through any exception and halt the program. It just continues normally but doesn't update in database.

Comment: Check the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery`, most likely it's not finding any rows to update so it returns 0.

Comment: Yes It returns 0.